# How to update in correct mode array using Promise function in React.useState?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, use-state

How to update State using Promise function in React.useState if it contains array.
I wrote simplified example of what I have tried to do

```
  function md5(file: any, base64?: boolean): Promise<unknown> {
    // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ...
    return null;
  };
  const [state, setState] = useState(
    [...Array(10).keys()].map(el => {
      return { name: `name${el}`, file: `file${el}`, hash: "" };
    })
  );
  state.forEach(el => {
    md5(el.file).then((hash: string) => {
      const newState = [
        ...state,
        {
          name: el.name,
          file: el.file,
          hash,
        },
      ];
      // console.log(state); == always not uptated
      setState(newState);
    });
  });
```

If I tried to use map for array function returns not hash but Promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `Promise.all` to wait for all `md5` calls to complete:

```
Promise.all(state.map(el => md5(el.file).then(hash => [hash, el])))
  .then((results) => {
    const newState = [
      ...state,
      ...results.map(([hash, el]) => ({ name: el.name, file: el.file, hash }))
    ];
    setState(newState);
  })
    .catch(handleErrors); // don't foget to catch errors
```

Another option would be to use a callback in `setState` so that the prior finished calls of `md5` don't get overwritten.

```
const newValue = { name: el.name, file: el.file, hash };
setState(state => [...state, newValue]);
```

Comment: Thx a lot. The second way is for me, because on each change i make another operations asynchronously